# Passing the pointer of an array into a funciton

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am currently writing code that takes an array of different char and num (to represent a ship for battle ship) and apply it into a function. In the main code below I execute exactly what I want to do, but when I try to put the array diff_ships into the function randomly_place_ships_on_board I get an error message. Any help would be really helpful.

Here is my header file

```
typedef struct game_board
{
    int board[10][10];
    int row;
    int col;
    char symbol;
}Game_Board;

typedef struct ships
{
    int legnth;
    char symbol;
}Ships;

int randomlly_place_ships_on_board(Ships *diff_ships[], Game_Board *player);
```

This is the code in main

```
Game_Board person, computer;
Ships diff_ships[5] = { {5, 'c'}, {4, 'b'}, {3, 'r'}, {3, 's'}, {2, 'd'} };

person.symbol = '~';
person.row = 10;
person.col = 10;
computer.symbol = '-';
computer.row = 10;
computer.col = 10;


printf("Player 1\n");
initalize_game_board(&person);
printf("\nPlayer 2\n");
initalize_game_board(&computer);

randomlly_place_ships_on_board(&diff_ships[5], &person);
```

Here is the code in main that works perfectly

```
printf("%c\n", diff_ships[0].symbol);
printf("%c\n", person.board[0][0]);
person.board[0][0] = diff_ships[0].symbol;
printf("%c\n", person.board[0][0]);
```

Here is the function I am trying to run the code in

```
int randomlly_place_ships_on_board(Ships *diff_ships[], Game_Board *player)
{
    int direction = 0, i = 0, cell_row = 0, cell_col = 0;

    cell_row = rand() % 6;
    cell_col = rand() % 10;

    printf("Placing ship\n");

                 //this call to an array causes an error
    printf("%c", diff_ships[0]->symbol);

     //this is the line also causing the error
    player->board[0][5] = diff_ships[0]->symbol;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the **address of** `&diff_ships[5]`? Just pass `diff_ships` and change the parameter in the function call to `Ships *diff_ships`. Why? `diff_ships` is already an *array*, which will be converted to a pointer when passed as a parameter to a function anyway. You are not changing the address in your function (e.g. allocating it and filling it in the function) -- so there is no need.

Comment: thanks this worked, Im still getting used to pointers and everything!

Comment: It will take time to have it all sink in. That's OK. Just slow down and work to understand what you have and what you need. You will do fine. (also enabling **warnings** with `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string and not accepting code until it compiles without warning with take care of 90% of the problems). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well, `&diff_ships[5]` is different from `diff_ships`, actually its equal to `diff_ships + 5`

Comment: Hah -- right you are, but that is a different matter that was corrected by the change anyway `:)`

Comment: BTW `randomly_place_ships_on_board` typo as `randomlly_place_ships_on_board`

Comment: `int randomlly_place_ships_on_board(Ships *diff_ships[], Game_Board *player)` --> `int randomlly_place_ships_on_board(Ships diff_ships[], Game_Board *player)`, `randomlly_place_ships_on_board(&diff_ships[5], &person);` --> `randomlly_place_ships_on_board(diff_ships, &person);` , `printf("%c", diff_ships[0]->symbol);` --> `printf("%c", diff_ships[0].symbol);`